# How specify "this:image" in custom function in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How do you write a custom function in GEE that takes a `this:` argument, e.g. in the way that `image.select(bands)` takes 'this:image' as it's first argument, and 'bands' as the second arg.

For example, I have a function that removes select bands from an image or image collection. Currently, it accepts args inside the parenthesis, like `selectNot(image, bands)`. How would I re-write this to accept the first argument, i.e. `image.selectNot(bands)`?

```
var selectNot = function(col, bandsToRemove){
  var image = ee.ImageCollection(col).first() // cast image to IC if necessary 
  var bandNames = image.bandNames() // get list of the band names
  var bandsToKeep = bandNames.removeAll(bandsToRemove) 
  return col.select(bandsToKeep)
}

// test
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
var image = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20170328T083601_20170328T084228_T35RNK")
print(selectNot(image, ['B1'])) // B1 should be removed
print(selectNot(collection, ['B1']).first()) // B1 should be removed
// end test
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/62ae541f28322b6d80693c6bc841c5c4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  You're prohibited from modifying the prototype of the objects provided in the ee namespace.